# GWT carousel panel with buttons for infinite banners loop

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new in GWT and I want to add to my website a carousel panel with simple banners (without image) and buttons (left and right) for infinite loop.

I'll appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in a couple of ways:

1. Find a javascript library with the carousel features you need (e.g. Bootstrap), and interface with it using GWT's JsInterop.
2. Find an existing GWT UI library that has the carousel features.  e.g. [gwtbootstrap3](https://github.com/treblereel/gwtbootstrap3)